# Data is not displayed in grid view in an ASP.NET web application using Wijmo and nockout Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, wijmo

I'm trying to view an ASP.NET page that will show Customer Actions Information in a grid. The grid will contain Action ID, Customer ID, Case ID, Action Date/Time, Action Type, Action By and Serial No. tabs.

The development work is being done in ASP.NET 4.5 using knockout.js and Bootstrap, and it is developed using 7-layered architecture. The layers are Common, Core, DAL(Data Access Layer), DTO (Data Transfer Object), Manager, Repository and Web.

So far I have created the Core class, factory class, repository interface, DTO class, form class, the manager class and interface, the repository class and the view file.

The code in the view file is given below:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Wijmo CSS and script -->
<link type="text/css" href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/metro/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet" title="metro-jqueryui" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-complete.all.2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- KnockoutJS for MVVM-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
//Create ViewModel
var CustomerActionsviewModel = {
pageSize: ko.observable(10),
pageIndex: ko.observable(0),
sortCommand: ko.observable("ActionID asc"),
dataRows: ko.observableArray([]),
totalRows: ko.observable(0),
sorted: function (e, data) {
    CustomerActionsviewModel.sortCommand(data.sortCommand);
},
paged: function (e, data) {
    CustomerActionsviewModel.pageIndex(data.newPageIndex);
},
load: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/CustomerAction/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "$callback",
        data: {
            $format: "json",
            $inlinecount: "allpages",
            $select: "ActionID,CustomerID,CaseID,ActionDateTime,ActionType,ActionBy,SlNo",
            $orderby: CustomerActionsviewModel.sortCommand(),
            $top: CustomerActionsviewModel.pageSize(),
            $skip: CustomerActionsviewModel.pageIndex() * CustomerActionsviewModel.pageSize(),
            "paging[pageIndex]": CustomerActionsviewModel.pageIndex(),
            "paging[pageSize]": CustomerActionsviewModel.pageSize()
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var data = result.d.results;
            var arr = [];

            $.each(data, function (i) {
                arr.push(new customerAction(data[i]));
            });
            CustomerActionsviewModel.totalRows(result.d.__count);
            CustomerActionsviewModel.dataRows(arr);
        }
      });
   }

};

 //Class constructor for grid row. Returns observable properties.
 var customerAction = function (data) {
 return {
    ActionID: ko.observable(data.ActionID),
    CustomerID: ko.observable(data.CustomerID),
    CaseID: ko.observable(data.CaseID),
    ActionDateTime: ko.observable(data.ActionDateTime),
    ActionType: ko.observable(data.ActionType),
    ActionBy: ko.observable(data.ActionBy),
    SlNo: ko.observable(data.SlNo)
    };
};
</script>

<div class="toolbar">
<label>Display: </label>
<select data-bind="value: pageSize, wijdropdown: {}">
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</div>
<table id="dataGrid" data-bind="
wijgrid: {
data: dataRows,
pageSize: pageSize,
pageIndex: pageIndex,
totalRows: totalRows,
allowPaging: true,
allowSorting: true,
sorted: sorted,
pageIndexChanged: paged,
columns: [
{ sortDirection: 'ascending', dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'Action ID', width: 60 },
{ dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'Customer ID', width: 60},
{ dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'Case ID', width: 60},
{ headerText: 'Action Date/Time', width: 100},
{ headerText: 'Action Type', width: 100 },
{ headerText: 'Action By', width: 100 },
{ dataType: 'number', dataFormatString: 'n0', headerText: 'Serial No', width: 60}]
}">
</table>

<script>
//Bind ViewModel and Event Handlers
$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(CustomerActionsviewModel);
CustomerActionsviewModel.load();
CustomerActionsviewModel.sortCommand.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    CustomerActionsviewModel.load();
});
CustomerActionsviewModel.pageIndex.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    CustomerActionsviewModel.load();
});
CustomerActionsviewModel.pageSize.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    CustomerActionsviewModel.load();
$(":wijmo-wijdropdown").wijdropdown("refresh");
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is, data is loaded from the database, but the loaded data is not viewed. Can anyone tell me where is the problem????

Comment: Do you get an error ? May be on client on client you get an error 500. Did you check the requests log of the web browser ?

Comment: @Damien No I didn't get any error. The web browser I'm using to view this page is Internet Explorer 8.